# Libcurl closes HTTPS connection each request

Tags: c++, curl, https, kerberos

We are using Kerberos to authenticate HTTPS request. We wish to reuse the connection for requests to same endpoint by using same curl handle. This works fine for HTTP connections. However, each rest request we sent will send two request, first will get 401 to get back authentication token and then 200 for the data. Then curl will close the connection and reconnect again for following rest request. This is extremely inefficient, is there a way to cut down all the authentication cost? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share the cURL command you're using?